# Tortoise Hg not detecting users created in SCM Manager (Mercurial)

Tags: version-control, mercurial, authorization, tortoisehg, scmmanager

I am a newbie to mercurial and SCM Manager. I installed SCM manger 1.20 for managing Mercurial repositories (OS - Windows 7) . I am using tortoise Hg at the client side .I am able to create users, repositories, groups and can give permissions to repositories in SCM manager. But Tortoise Hg at the client side is not detecting the users created in SCM Manager. My aim is to give the users created in SCM manager the permission to clone and commit using Tortoise Hg. Anyone knows the solution please help.

Comment: Tortoise Hg does not "detect" users on the server.  When you try to access a protected repository it will ask you for the username and password (if not already supplied) and passes them to the server.  Can you post the output log of a failing command please so that we can see what is going on?

Comment: @Steve: Hi Steve Kaye, thanks for your response. I will explain the whole scenario. I creates a mercurial repository using SCM Manager, creates a user and I add that user under the permission tab of the repository. After creating the repository I am getting a URL 1) http://localhost:8087/hg/RepoNew and a checkout URL 2) http://arjun@localhost:8087/hg/RepoNew. Here "RepoNew" is the created repository and "arjun" is the user. I can clone with the first URL by giving the System's user credentials. If I use the second it asks for password but shows "abort:authorization failed" on submitting.

Comment: The difference between the first and second URL is that the second has an embedded username.  You should be able to use either URL all the time.  If you use the first, when authentication is required, you'll be prompted for both username and password.  From the error, my guess is that either you didn't enter the right password, or you didn't configure the user in SCM Manager correctly.  Their [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scmmanager) should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your configuration of TortoiseHg and the repository at SCM-Manager.
At SCM-Manager side:

- Open the permission tab of "RepoNew" and make sure that the user "arjun" has "write" or "owner" permission.
- Copy the URL near "hg clone", in your case

  ```
  http://arjun@localhost:8087/hg/RepoNew
  ```

At TortoiseHg side:

- Start TortoiseHg Workbench
- Click on File ==> Settings
- Choose "Commit" on the left side.
- Type in your Username. SCM-Manager likes the format "YourName < your@email.xy>" as username (Note: this is a global setting. You can change settings per repository later).
- Click ok, and choose File ==> Clone Repository... from the menu.
- Paste the URL in the source field you got from the SCM-Manager
- Choose a destination directory
- Click on the clone button.
- You will be prompted for a password.

If this was successful, this repository should be configured already for pushing. Try to add a file, commit and finally push it to the server.